# How can I send multiple HTTP requests to a URL using Axios and stop sending once I receive a response from one of the request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, web, axios

I am new to javascript and trying to write a script that will send multiple HTTP requests to a web server using Axios. The server is designed in such a way that it will send response randomly to a request. Now, I want the script to stop sending the requests once it receives one response. The basic code which I could write yet is:

```
while (1) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/ubuntu_default.html', { withCredentials: true }).then(function (response) {
        document.body.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
        break;
        });

    function generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response) {
        return response.data;
    }
}
```

Assume this .js file will be present in the client's browser.

Comment: How or what triggers the api call you are making from axios?

Comment: The client first requests '/index.html' and in response the server sends back the HTML code with two js files. one is this js code and other is axios.min.js (available at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js). Now the client retrieves these two js files. After this, the client requests the 'http://localhost:8080/ubuntu_default.html'. For this, the server sends response randomly to one of the requests.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that suggests that it's triggered more than once. If you have some kind of loop, it's important to share that too

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the relevant info. This is hard to read/debug

Comment: @Evert Edited the base code in the question now..

Answer (score 0):

Edit: based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052747/how-can-i-send-multiple-http-requests-to-a-url-using-axios-and-stop-sending-once/63057504?noredirect=1#comment111614706_63057504) op just wants to poll an endpoint and stop once he gets a response.

Example code:

```
(async() { 
    let r = await poll('http://localhost:8080/ubuntu_default.html');
    console.log(r); 
})();

async function poll(endpoint) {
    let countOfError = 0;
    const maxErrors = 10;
    let resp = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
            resp = await axios.get(endpoint, { withCredentials: true }));
            
            //check if resp is "success" then break;    
            //What does a successful response look like?
            if (resp.data.success) break;            
        } catch (e) {
            //console.error(e);  optional
            countOfErrors += 1;
            if (countOfErrors > maxErrors) break;
        }
    }

    return resp;
}
```

### old answer

You could use something like [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

```js
let promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i<10; i++)
   promises.push(
     axios.get('http://localhost:8080/ubuntu_default.html', 
               { withCredentials: true }));

Promise.race(promises).then( generateSuccessHTMLOutput ); 
//Called with whichever promise fulfills first
```

Comment: So I am using this code but still the script is sending requests even after I receive the response for one of the requests sent earlier: let promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i<10; i++)
   promises.push(
     axios.get('http://localhost:8080/ubuntu_default.html', 
               { withCredentials: true }));

Promise.race(promises).then( function (response) {
      return response.data
    });

Comment: Are all the requests to the same page? If so, then you don't need to send in parallel...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All the requests are on the same page. But I am not sure how to change this code for that. Also, when I run this code, it is showing the error like this " Error: Unexpected token '{' "